# SFML drawing on absolute position with reference to window

Tags: c++, sfml

My current sfml project has some views. The views change both size and center. I could mathematically calculate my desired position but that seems like too much work. Does there exist any built in function I could use?

Comment: So your position isn't absolute - its relative to window. What for you are trying to do it? Maybe there is better solution to this - for example: for user interface.

Comment: My camera/view move around with the players. Now I want to overlay the score board on the window. It needs to always be in one particular part of the window, regardless of where the views are pointing at.

Comment: So there is better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`sf::RenderWindow::getDefaultView()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a718b1aa6296bf855171699cc18251ced) as follows (Assuming you have a `sf::RenderWindow` called `window`):

```
// First draw all objects that you have set a view for
window.setView(yourView);

window.draw(viewObject);

window.setView(window.getDefaultView()); // Reset the view to the window's default one

// ... Set the position and all (You can do this before as well)

window.draw(yourScoreBoard);

window.display(); // You should see your views with a score board overlay that
                  // stays in the same place
```

If you want to draw things that are have their own views, then first set the view of the window to that view, and then draw your object.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want an overlay. UI overlays are done using separate render texture. You should split your game to two render targets:

- a render target for in-game things (players, monsters, spells etc.)
- a render target for UI (score, health etc.)

Both render targets are also textures ([`sf::RenderTexture`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php)). You render everything to them as they were simple windows. Once you have them in separate textures, you use them to render everything using sprites inside window:

```
sf::RenderTexture inGameRT;
sf::RenderTexture uiRT;

while(window.isOpen())
{
    // event loop

    // now drawing in-game (only example):
    inGameRT.clear();
    // std::vector<sf::Sprite*> players; // or sth other...
    for(auto const & player : players)
         inGameRT.draw(*player);

    inGameRT.display(); // don't forget it



    // now drawing UI (only example):
    uiRT.clear();
    // std::vector<sf::Sprite*> uiWidgets; // or sth other...
    for(auto const & widget : uiWidgets)
         uiRT.draw(*widget);

    uiRT.display(); // don't forget it

    // Once you drawn everything, you can display two textures inside window

    window.clear();

    sf::Sprite inGameSprite{inGameRT.getTexture()};
    sf::Sprite uiSprite{uiRT.getTexture()};
    window.draw(inGameSprite);
    window.draw(uiSprite);
    window.display();
}
```

`sf::View`s can be also applied to `sf::RenderTarget`s.